# Coldfusion.navigate not working with internet explorer 8

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I'm using the following:

```
 function callbackblank(text) 
    { 

    } 

    function errorHandler(code, msg) 
    { 
                alert("Error!!! " + code + ": " + msg); 
    } 
    function FindCustomers()
    {
                ColdFusion.navigate("SearchResults/customerResults.cfm", 'CustomerFindDiv', callbackblank,  errorHandler, 'POST', 'FindCustomerForm');
            }

<cfform action="#CurrentPage#?intApprovalID=#url.intApprovalID#" name="FindCustomerForm" id="FindCustomerForm">
            <cfinput type="hidden" name="intApprovalID" value="#url.intApprovalID#">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input onkeydown="javascript: FindCustomers();" name="strCustomerFirstName" <cfif isDefined("form.strCustomerFirstName") and #form.strCustomerFirstName# neq "">value="<cfoutput>#form.strCustomerFirstName#</cfoutput>"</cfif> ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name: </td>
                    <td><input onkeydown="javascript: FindCustomers();" name="strCustomerLastName" required="yes" <cfif isDefined("form.strCustomerLastName") and #form.strCustomerLastName# neq "">value="<cfoutput>#form.strCustomerLastName#</cfoutput>"</cfif> ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="submitit" type="hidden" value="Search" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </cfform>
```

This works fine in i.e. 10, but fails to post the form to customerResults.cfm in i.e. 10. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? It's possible that IE 8 is no longer supposed in the related JS library that ships with newer versions of ColdFusion. There are a number of issues like that with the JS libraries related to CF's UI controls. You might want to ditch CFFORM and figure out how to write the plain JavaScript required to do what you need done.

Comment: CF 10. I have no idea why I didn't just write it in plain javascript. I think coldfusion is making me lazy.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg I hear that.  cfform does crowd things unnecessarily when it renders client side. makes for some ugly code.